# How to compile program that includes QImage?

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to compile a program using clang, and the program simply includes a QImage head file, but the compilation gives the following error:

```
$ clang main.cpp
main.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'QImage' file not found
#include <QImage>
         ^~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

I have installed `sudo apt install qt5-default` on my Ubuntu 20.04, how to compile this program?

```
#include <QImage>

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First of all, the `clang` driver program is for **C**, for C++ use `clang++`.

Comment: Clang by itself does not know where to find the Qt framework on your computer. You should use some build system such as `qmake` or `cmake`. I recommend that you should google for some good Qt tutorials (e.g. on youtube tutorial by VoidRealms) instead of reinventing all basic stuff yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary but it is easier to use QT's own build system when using QT. For this project, it is as simple as creating a `qmake.pro` file that contains the following lines:

```
TARGET = your_program_name
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

and run `qmake` to generate a `Makefile`, and run `make` to use that `Makefile` to build.

`qmake` generates a `Makefile` that contains all the necessary flags and paths to compile a Qt project.

You can examine which compile and link flags are used in the output of that `make` command and use those flags in your own build system if you like. However, it will not be portable.

To give you an idea, flags on my system are:

```
# compile
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -Wextra -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore -I. -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o main.o main.cpp
# link
g++ -Wl,-O1 -o your_program_name main.o   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so -lGL -lpthread
```